# Decorator for cheking any function annotation type

Tags: python, decorator

i want to design a decorator to check any function annotation type and if it has similar type then run function.
can python do such this thing??
if python can, please help me!!

```
def foo (a:int):
    if foo.__annotations__.get('a') == type(a):
        pass

def boo (b:str):
    if boo.__annotations__.get('b') == type(b):
        pass
```

and another thing is annotations is a dict type, i want such this :

```
from type import FunctionType
def check (f:FunctionType):
    result = True
    k = [k for k in f.__annotations__.keys()]
    v = [v for v in f.__annotations__.values()]
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if v[i] != type(k[i]): #but we don't access to the type of k[i] out of th f function
            result = False
    return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the idea correctly, perhaps this code will help you:

```
from types import FunctionType

def check(f: FunctionType):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = True

        # check args
        keys = tuple(f.__annotations__.keys())
        for ar in enumerate(args):
            if not isinstance(ar[1], f.__annotations__.get(keys[ar[0]])):
                result = False
                break

        if result:
            # check kwargs
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                if not isinstance(v, f.__annotations__.get(k)):
                    result = False
                    break

        if result:
            f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Example usage:

```
@check
def foo(a: str, b: int = None):
    print(f"a  = {a}")
    print(f"b  = {b}")


# Example 1: a=324, b=32:
foo(234, b=32)
# result: function not executed

# Example 2: a="abc", b="zzz":
foo("abc", b="zzz")
# result: function not executed

# Example 3: a="qwe", b= not set:
foo("qwe")
# result: function executed, output:
# a  = qwe
# b  = None

# Example 4: a="abc", b=99:
foo("abc", 99)
# result: function executed, output:
# a  = abc
# b  = 99
```

The decorator checks the argument types, and if everything is in order, it executes the function, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

something like this.

```
import inspect
import functools


def check(func):
    msg = "Expected type {etype} for {para} got {got}"
    para = inspect.signature(func).parameters
    keys = tuple(para.keys())

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        def do_check(anno,value,para):
            if not isinstance(value, anno):
                raise TypeError(msg.format(etype=anno,
                    para=para,
                    got=type(value)))

        for i,value in  enumerate(args):
            anno = para[keys[i]].annotation
            do_check(anno, value, keys[i])

        for arg_name,value in  kwargs.items():
            anno = para[arg_name].annotation
            do_check(anno, value, arg_name)

        ret = func(*args,**kwargs)
        if "return" in func.__annotations__:
            anno = func.__annotations__["return"]
            do_check(anno, ret, "return")
        return ret
    return wrapper

@check
def test(a:int,b:str) -> str:
    return 'aaa'

@check
def test2(a:int,b:str) -> str:
    return 123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import functools
def annotations_checker(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        TrueFalseChecker=True
        keys=tuple(func.__annotations__.keys())
        for key_num in range(len(keys)):
            if func.__annotations__[keys[key_num]]!=type(args[key_num]):
                break
        else:
            value=func(*args,*kwargs)
            return value
        return

    return wrapper
```

and you can use @annotations_checker decorator for any python method / python function to check type annotations
like:

```
@annotations_checker
def test(str_example:str,int_example:int,second_str_example:str):
    print("if you can see this, the args and annonations type are same!") 
test(1,"2",3) #the function will not work
test("1",1,"testtest") #function will work
```